# How do you control the color scheme of the geom_line in the below code?

Tags: graph, colors, yaxis

I have a graph that combines a barchart and connected scatterplot, grouped by timeframe. I already used the scale_fill_manual function to manipulate the color of the barchart. R is using default colors for the temperature lines above the bar graph. I tried using scale_fill_manual again but it doens't work and I can't seem to assign colors in my case_when function. Is there any way I can change them (I'd like them to be yellow, orange, and red to show temperature rising over time). Thanks!

```
am_graph <- ggplot((am), aes(x=factor(Month,levels=month.abb))) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Precipitation, group = Timeframe, fill = Timeframe), width = .7, position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Mean_Temperature*10, group = Timeframe, col = case_when(
    Timeframe == "1970-2000" ~ "1970-2000",
    Timeframe== 2018 ~ "2018",
    TRUE ~ "2041-2060"))) +
  geom_point(size = 0.25, aes(y = Mean_Temperature*10, group = Timeframe)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Timeframe") +
  ggtitle("Alto Mayo Monthly Climate Conditions (1970-2060)") +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Precipitation (mm)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 220, by = 20), limit = c(0, 220), expand = c(0, 0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name = "Temperature (°C)")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue2", "steelblue2", "royalblue1")) +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work for anyone wondering!

```
am_graph <- ggplot((am), aes(x=factor(Month,levels=month.abb))) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Precipitation, group = Timeframe, fill = Timeframe), width = .7, position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(size = 0.5, aes(y = Mean_Temperature*10, group = Timeframe, col = case_when(
    Timeframe == "1970-2000" ~ "1970-2000",
    Timeframe== 2018 ~ "2018",
    TRUE ~ "2041-2060"))) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, aes(y = Mean_Temperature*10, group = Timeframe)) +
  ggtitle("Alto Mayo Monthly Climate Conditions (1970-2060)") +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Precipitation (mm)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 220, by = 20), limit = c(0, 220), expand = c(0, 0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name = "Temperature (°C)")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Precipitation", values = c("lightblue2", "steelblue2", "royalblue1")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightgoldenrod2", "darkorange2", "tomato3")) +
  guides(col = guide_legend("Temperature")) +
  theme_classic()
```